# Obtener datos API netcore react

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Tengo problemas con un proyecto creado en visual studio "ASP.NET Core con Reactjs" he realizado una API que obtiene datos de una tabla SQL Server, y una vez comprobado que las peticiones funcionan con postman,  creo una tabla desde react para mostrar los datos pero no logro comunicación entre ambas partes.
Para esto he generado un .env donde tengo las variables de conexión que utilizo en un fetch, pero no se porqué no obtengo los datos, o algún error que pueda identificar...

fichero .env:

```
        REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:5001/api/
        REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH=http://localhost:5001/Photos/
```

Componente desde donde intento obtener los datos:

```
     export class Department extends Component {

     constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state={deps:[]}
         }

      refreshList() {
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'department')    //
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {this.setState({ deps: data });
        });
        }

     componentDidMount() {  this.refreshList(); }
     componentDidUpdate() { this.refreshList(); }


    render() {

         const { deps } = this.state;

         return (

            <div>
                <Table>
               
                <tbody>
                    {deps.map(dep =>
                        <tr key={dep.id}>
                            <td>{dep.id}</td>
                            <td>{dep.name}</td>
                            <td>Edit / Delete</td>
                        </tr>)}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Estructura de la solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el problema modificando el fichero de configuración .env cambiandole el puerto donde responde la API ya que al correr el proyecto inicia ambos procesos al mismo tiempo.